# Different Urls for mobile and desktop homepages

Tags: plugins

Am using two themes on my wordpress blog, one for pc and the other for mobile. The front page is showing a well designed static page in the pc view and i want it that way. But when i view on mobile i see an empty page.

What am trying to do is, when a user on pc enters mydomain.com, i need them to see the desktop static page and when on mobile and enters mydomain.com i want them to be redirected to mydomain.com/postpage

NB: *am using a plugin to switch the themes (mobile smart)*

my blog is https://dhithub.com.ng/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish this using Wordpress alone since there is no way (that I know) for Wordpress (or PHP for that matter) to detect if it's desktop or mobile. I'd imagine you could use some simple Javascript however to [detect if you're on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/1231466) and then use `window.location` to redirect to your subpage.

Comment: thanks danbrellis for the response but i found a way that to with a plugin called Any Mobile theme switcher pro. With that i was able to set different homepages for any mobile device.